# Shell parameter expansion in the context of shell vs make

Tags: shell, makefile

I have a makefile that does a little plain shell scripting ahead of the actual task.  The idea is to increment the version number before continuing.

```
SHELL := /bin/bash # bash is needed for manipulation of version number
PKG_NAME=FuncMap
PKG_VERSION=1.1.1

## Increment the z version of x.y.z

XYZ=$(subst ., , $(PKG_VERSION))
X=$(word 1, $(XYZ))
Y=$(word 2, $(XYZ))
Z=$(word 3, $(XYZ))
Z2=$$(($(Z)+1))
NEW_VERSION=$(addsuffix $(addprefix .,$(Z2)), $(addsuffix $(addprefix ., $(Y)), $(X)))
TGZ=$(PKG_NAME)_$(NEW_VERSION).tar.gz

all: info check

info:
    @echo "Package:" $(PKG_NAME)
    @echo "Old/New version numbers:" $(PKG_VERSION) $(NEW_VERSION)
    @echo "TGZ is:" $(TGZ)

check: $(TGZ)
    R CMD check --as-cran $(TGZ)
```

Now when I run this, the value of `$(TGZ)` reports correctly from rule "info", but as the target of "check", it sees the unexpanded version (is that the right word?):

```
Package: FuncMap
Old/New version numbers: 1.1.1 1.1.2
TGZ is: FuncMap_1.1.2.tar.gz
make: *** No rule to make target `FuncMap_1.1.$((1+1)).tar.gz', needed by `check'.  Stop.
```

How can I get the line `check: $(TGZ)` to be interpreted as `check: FuncMap_1.1.2.tar.gz`?  I'm mixed up as to environment/context, need to quote or not and which kind, etc.

Comment: The `$((...))` syntax is a shell expansion. That doesn't work in make itself. So make can't expand it. If you `echo '$(TGZ)'` (in single quotes) in the recipe you'll see the same non-expansion. You can't get make to do what you want here without using `$(shell)` explicitly to involve the shell at make time.

Comment: Thanks @EtanReisner as always (you are witnessing my travails in detail).  I don't quite understand your last sentence.  Do you mean I have to invoke make differently at the command line?  I know people do what I'm trying to do, maybe I need to work harder at finding a working example out there.  But I would learn less that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to Etan's answer: it works in a recipe because a recipe is sent to the shell and the shell interprets the result and so prints what you expect.  If you pass the literal string `$((1+1))` to the shell the shell expands that to `2`.

But you can't use that value in a makefile context (as part of a target or prerequisite name for example) because the makefile is not the shell, and the makefile doesn't interpret the result as the shell would.  If you use the string `$$((1+1))` in a makefile context it expands that as the literal string `$((1+1))`, not `2`.

You need to use the shell to perform math:

```
Z2 := ${shell echo $$(($(Z)+1))}
```

Comment: You could also use the [GNU Make Standard Library](http://gmsl.sourceforge.net/) if you really wanted to do the math in make itself but I don't know that's a useful direction to go for this.

Comment: OK, thank you, though telling the shell to echo something as a form of input is certainly tortured. Unfortunately, running make still gives an error: `TGZ is: FuncMap_1.1.2.tar.gz; make: *** No rule to make target FuncMap_1.1.2.tar.gz, needed by check.  Stop.` So the target now appears correct, but is somehow unacceptable.

Comment: No, no, nope, my bad, I was being dense.  Simple example didn't have the build step.  Once that was put back, all good.

Comment: Thanks again for your clear explanation of how the shell and makefile behave differently.  That has been plaguing me...

Comment: No one, certainly not me, ever claimed that makefile was a Turing-complete language (although GMSL implies it might be close).  If you don't like dropping into the shell for math operations you can build your version of GNU make (4.0 and above) with Guile as a built-in extension language and use that.